# JProfiler Negates -parameter Compiler Argument

Tags: java, jprofiler, jdbi

I am using JDBI for database access. As recommended, I am using the `-parameter` compiler argument to allow JDBI to get parameter names via reflection. This works perfectly well. Except that, if I try to profile the running code using JProfiler in full instrumentation mode, JDBI seems to lose the ability to resolve the parameter names. It seems strange to me that JProfiler is interfering with compilation instructions, but, nonetheless that appers to be the case. The precise error I get from JDBI is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Instance factory 'public MyClass(int,long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,long,long,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean)' could not match any parameter to any columns in the result set. Verify that the Java compiler is configured to emit parameter names, that your result set has the columns expected, annotate the parameter names explicitly with @ColumnName, or annotate nullable parameters as @Nullable
```

Is there any way to configure JProfiler to prevent it from causing this error?

Comment: did you find a solution or cause yet?

Comment: You are not alone. Is comforting to know I'm not the only one with such issues.

Answer (score 0):

When I opened a ticket with EJ-Technologies, they said "If classes are retransformed, the Hotspot VM unfortunately loses the method parameter name attribute."

This appears to only be a problem when I use "Instrumentation" instead of "Sampling". So, my current work-around is only to use "Sampling", which means some features are unavailable, but I was still able to get enough information for my purposes.